# z-index displays incorrectly in safari

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've created a nice little CSS styling to put three images into a 3D display, left and right images put into perspective and then placed behind the central image.  It works perfectly in Chrome but in Safari the order gets reversed.
I also placed them correctly in Firefox and IE just without the 3D stylings.

Here's the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>triple screen css</title>
<link href="screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="triple-panel">
  <div class="left-img shrink">
    <img src="images/img2.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="center-img">
    <img src="images/img1.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="right-img shrink">
    <img src="images/img3.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.triple-panel > div {
display:inline;
float:left;
perspective: 500;
-webkit-perspective: 500;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transition-property: perspective;
}

.triple-panel img {
display:inline;
margin: 2em auto;
border:10px solid #fcfafa;
/* ADDS DROP SHADOW */
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px #888;
box-shadow:0 3px 10px #888;
}

.shrink {
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform:scale(.75,.75);
-ms-transform:scale(.75,.75); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:scale(.75,.75); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:scale(.75,.75); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:scale(.75,.75); /* Opera */
}

.left-img img {
position:relative;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-30deg);
left:50px;
 }

.center-img img{
position:relative;
top:0;
}

.right-img img {
position:relative;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg);
left:-50px;
}

.left-img, .right-img {
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}

.center-img {
position:relative;
z-index:30;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to be the way safari renders the 3D transform, even if I reposition the center image to the end of the html and position it over the background passes through it.

Comment: Further update, it actually seems to work as designed when posted into an orchard build.  I'd still like to know why it doesn't work as it appears above though.  Any ideas?